# What's the best way of checking that a value is a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

In other words, how do I check this: `1529490236830` as opposed to other values like `'abc'`, `'1970/00/12'`, etc?

I wanted to do something like `Date.now('s')`, but this also produces a timestamp.

Comment: Try `new Date()` and pass the value as an argument to the constructor. It returns **Invalid Date** for the values it cannot parse. Additionally, you can check if all the characters in the value are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let isTimeStamp = Number(milliSeconds)? new Date(Number(milliSeconds)).getTime() >0 :false;
```

isTimeStamp will give true for valid timestamp for any date newer than 'Thu Jan 01 1970';

for dates before that you can use just:

```
var isTimeStamp = Number(milliSeconds)? new Date(Number(milliSeconds)).getTime():false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using following scripts, a given value is a timestamp or not in javascript

var isTimestamp = (new Date('2018-06-20')).getTime() > 0; 
console.log(isTimestamp) // true

var isTimestamp = (new Date('test')).getTime() > 0; 
console.log(isTimestamp) // false